# Using plyr to obtain all strings in dataframe beginning with a string

Tags: r, regex, plyr

I have a data frame and I'm trying to obtain all strings in there that begin with "RLF" and put them in a list. I tried using the dlply function in plyr, but I couldn't get the syntax quite right.

```
dlply(.data = unformatted_table,.variables = 1:ncol(unformatted_table), .fun = strsplit("RLF") ,.inform = TRUE)
```

I looked around alot and couldn't apply the solutions to my problem. Also, please let me know if there's a better way than using dlply.

Comment: `lapply(unformatted_table, grep, pattern="^RLF", value=TRUE)` in boring old R. Or even `lapply(unformatted_table, function(x) x[substr(x,1,3)=="RLF"] )`

Comment: *plyr* is like the 1980s of R.

Comment: @RichScriven - lots of good came out of the 80s... :-P

Comment: @thelatemail Can you explain what the first solution does. especially the exponent mark?

Comment: @thelatemail - Exactly my point!  It was good for its time, but has been developed into something even better.

Comment: @EzraBekele - It's a regular expression, see `?regex` - The `^` means "start of a string"

Comment: @thelatemail Thank you so much!

Comment: @thelatemail maybe post as an answer?